# Representation of exponential by a finite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-function

In the simplest case, I know that the expression $\exp({\frac{x_i + x_j}{2}})$, where $x_{i,j} \in \mathbb{R}$ can be represented by the following

$$
\sum_{k=1}^nf_{i,k}f_{j,k} = \exp({\frac{x_i + x_j}{2}})
$$

I know this is possible, I just can't see how to do it.

Something I have been considering, for n = 2, is the following

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2k-1}}{(2k-1)!} = \exp(x)
$$

but I can't see a way of generalising this, or even if this is the correct route.  Any thoughts on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\sum_k e^{(x_i+x_k)\over2}e^{(x_j+x_k)\over2}=e^{(x_i+x_j)\over 2}\sum_k e^{x_k}$, so that choosing a normalization $Z=\sum_k e^{x_k}$ you can solve for $f_{ik}={1\over \sqrt Z}e^{(x_i+x_k)\over2}$ .

More generally, if you think of $e^{(x_i+x_j)\over 2}$ as a matrix $A_{ij} = u^T u$ with $u_i = e^{x_i\over2}$, you see that your equation is $F^2 = u^Tu$, and assuming $F={1\over \sqrt Z} u^Tu$ will get you $F^2={1\over Z}u^T(uu^T)u$, and $uu^T$ is a scalar, so setting $Z=uu^T$ solves.

Comment: Thanks, this is really nice.  I wonder if there is a generalisation to $\exp(g(\frac{x_i + x_j}{2}))$?  It seems the factorisation used in the first part of the argument won't hold for the general $g()$

Comment: In the more general case, you can still treat it as a matrix, and try and find it's "square root".

Comment: Yeah, I've been struggling with that, but I will carry on.  NB. - I understand your answer, but at first read the notation is a little confusing, since it seems like you're summing over the index $k$, when really $Z = ne^{x_k}$

Comment: Now I dont understand you. I am indeed summing over $k$ . $k$ is a running index, just like you use it.

Comment: for $n=2$: $e^{(x_i+x_1)\over 2}e^{(x_j+x_1)\over 2}+e^{(x_i+x_2)\over 2}e^{(x_j+x_2)\over 2} = e^{(x_i+x_j)\over2}[e^{x_1}+e^{x_2}]$

Comment: Yes, you are of course correct.  I've just double checked my workings and I had made a stupidity in my notation.  Apologies.